# Azure Function not Able to Read/Access local.settings.json when Debugging w/ VS2017 for Mac

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Empty/null value returned when attempting to read from the local.settings.json config file when debugging an Azure Function locally using VS2017 for Mac...  after scanning the internet I wasn't able to determine if this is a known issue or if there is a work around.  This is how I'm accessing the configuration settings:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connName"].ConnectionString
```

This works fine if the Function app is debugged on a Windows Machine (same git code base)

Comment: Not sure about that particular issue, but azure functions can also read from environment variables. So if you can't find a solution to local settings on a mac, you can use environment variables to store/get those values.

Comment: Thanks, will try that as a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure function v2 running on runtime 2.x(.net core) doesn't support ConfigurationManager any more. See [Azure Team's reply on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/328#issuecomment-355697529).

When I debug a v2 function on Windows, `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException` thrown. And v1 still works well as you have found.

So as @mariocatch has said, try to read enviroment variables instead.

Two options for you to refer.

1. Read environment variables directly

   ```
   string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:connName");
   ```
2. Add `ExecutionContext context` to your function method parameters and read local settings.

   ```
   [FunctionName("FunctionName")]
   public static void Run(...,ExecutionContext context)
   {
       var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
           .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
       string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("connName");
       .....
   }
   ```